# Display line number where error occurred in DB2 stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw, debugging, exception

I have added an EXIT handler in my procedure that captures the SQLSTATE and SQLCODE, and even found a way to get the procedure name, but I also need to know where the error occurred.  Suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
declare EXIT handler for SQLEXCEPTION
begin
    select sysibm.routine_specific_name, SQLSTATE, SQLCODE 
    into v_sp_name, v_sqlstate, v_sqlcode 
    from sysibm.sysdummy1;

    call dbms_output.put_line('Error in '||v_sp_name ' ['||v_sqlstate, v_sqlcode||']');
end;
```

Comment: What Db2 version? I presume it's Db2 for LUW.

Comment: Yes, DB2 LUW and version 11.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on a currently supported version of Db2 for LUW (11.1 or 11.5) you can use either [`DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0061936.html)  or [`DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0061937.html) in your signal handler to log the troubleshooting information.

Comment: Thank you.  This looks like it prints out a message that contains the line number where this command is executed.  So, yes I can use it in the signal handler to get a general idea of where the error is, but I have not been able to get the line number of the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add debugging code into your procedures to indicate progress within the procedure.

Otherwise, you could explore the [routine debugger in IBM Data Studio](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS62YD_4.1.1/com.ibm.debug.spd.plsql.doc/topics/cbsovrv.html) to help you find errors in SQL Stored Procedures

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I forgot to mention I wanted it for error logging.